# Wordpress ContactForm 7 Error Sending message

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I installed the plugin contactform 7 on my wordpress. Everytime I try to send the message the error :

```
There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.
```

will appear.

I checked all my settings, desinstall and reinstall the plugin but always the same problem.

My form:

```
<label> Your Name (required)
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Your Email (required)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Subject
    [text your-subject] </label>

<label> Your Message
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[submit "Send"]
```

My mail option:

```
To: info@mycompany.com
From: [your-name] <info@mycompany.com>
Subject: Company "[your-subject]"
Additional Headers: Reply-To: [your-email]
Message body: From: [your-name] <[your-email]>
Subject: [your-subject]

Message Body:
[your-message]

-- 
This e-mail was sent from a contact form on Company (https://company.com)
```

I did not find any answer to this problem in the docs file

Comment: change from email address: from “info@mydomai” to “wordpress@domain”.

Comment: @GufranHasan Thanks but it does not resolve my problem. I did change from from: info@mydomain.com to wordpress@mydomain.com but still same error

Comment: Okay, did you set up smtp for it? or you can use smtp plugin for it. please try it.

Comment: @GufranHasan I did not find any place to setup smtp. Do you know by chance which plugin can be used for that?

Comment: there are many plugins avaliable for it. you can use this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install smtp plugin to send email template.
There are many smtp plugins are available email setting in WordPress.
You can also use below plugin, It will work for you.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/